# String to DateTime convertion for the Date Property in the model

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I'm trying to pass an ajax object to a controller method. I'm using a date property in the model. But after debugger hit on the controller method, date value become default date like `{01-01-0001 00:00:00}` instead of a specific date. But other properties are getting actual value. In the ajax object `dataParams`, date is in string format. In model, it is declared as `DateTime` datatype. So, I tried to convert the `string` value to the `Date` format using below syntax. But it doesn't help. Can anyone suggest.

JavaScript:

```
var dataParams = {                    
        MDate: new Date(MDate),  //Date.parse(MDate),
        Status: "hh",
        CountryID: 8
        }
$.ajax({
        url: '../Monitoring/ActionGrid',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: "html",
        datatype: "application/json",
        data: dataParams,
        cache: true,
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Expires': '0'
        },
        success: function (dataResponse) {
            //..
        }, failure: function (data) {
            //..
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //..
        }
    });
```

MonitoringController:

```
public JsonResult ActionGrid(ActionEntity actionEntity)
{
    //..
}
```

ActionEntity Model:

```
public class ActionEntity
{        
    public string CountryID { get; set; }        
    public string Status { get; set; }        
    public DateTime MDate { get; set; }        
}
```

Here is the value if we check console.log(MDate) before sending the ajax request.

[image]

But I'm getting output of `var date = new Date(MDate);` as `Invalid Date` and output of `var date = Date.parse(MDate);` as `NaN`.

Comment: Since DateTime doesn't allow null, 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM is the default value for DateTime, and is used when there is no valid value to be parsed as a DateTime .

Try adding a console.log(dataParams) or console.log(MDate) before sending the ajax request and attach the console output to the question.

Comment: What ASP.NET version are you using?  Have you tried to send the same request with Postman? Also note that providing body to GET requests has [no defined semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/2501279)

Comment: I have attached output of console.log(MDate) also.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 version. And I'm using ASP.Net Core MVC.

Comment: I think the date needs to be in ISO format to be auto-converted to DateTime by C#?  Try `MDate: new Date(MDate).toISOString()` in your dataParams var.

Comment: But I'm getting output of `var date = new Date(MDate);` as `Invalid Date` and output of `var date = Date.parse(MDate);` as `NaN`. But `MDate` has date value that i have attached to the question.